# Python Pandas: How to group group two colums into a common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created a pandas dataframe from several CSV files.

Now there are some columns that represent the same content.
I want to group these columns into a common column in this data frame.

```
Now:

0  X  Y
1  6  
2     7
3  1
4     5
```

I want:

```
0  X  
1  6  
2  7
3  1
4  5
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are the missing values represented? The empty string or `NaN`?

Comment: mixed. Some NaN, some empty.

Answer (score 2):

#### Assuming those are empty strings `''`

Use `groupby` with a callable that converts `'Y'` to `'X'`

```
df.mask(df.eq('')).groupby(lambda x: {'Y': 'X'}.get(x, x), axis=1).first()

   0  X
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  3  1
3  4  5
```

---

Otherwise, ignore the `mask`

```
df.groupby(lambda x: {'Y': 'X'}.get(x, x), axis=1).first()

   0  X
0  1  6
1  2  7
2  3  1
3  4  5
```

Comment: the problem is that the empty fields are filled differently. some are empty, some are filled with 'nan'. there are also rows, there without any values in X or Y.           for information: the values ​​are floats

Answer (score 1):

May check with `fillna`

```
df.X.mask(df.X.eq('')).fillna(df.Y)
Out[232]: 
0    6.0
1    7.0
2    1.0
3    5.0
Name: X, dtype: float64
```

Comment: in fact, the column name looks like this:. 'Name-x'

Answer (score 0):

You can force the `dtype` to be `str`/`object` and then do horizontal concatenation/summation as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['6', '', '1', ''], 'Y': ['', 7, '', 5]})

df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)

# returns the following Series which you can assign to a new column of your dataframe
0   6
1   7
2   1
3   5
```